# How to correctly define (function || function) inside a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript

This works:

```
<div id="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var Base64Encode = window.btoa || CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify;

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = Base64Encode("Please work.");
</script>
```

However, this:

```
<div id="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var Test = {
    Base64Encode: window.btoa || CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify
};

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = Test.Base64Encode("Please work.");
</script>
```

Generates an error of "TypeError: 'btoa' called on an object that does not implement interface Window."

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kAGU2/

Why does the first example work but the second one emit that error?  What's the correct way to fix this particular error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does the first example work but the second one emit that error?

When the function is called as `Base64Encode()`, the [`this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is implicitly set to `window`. However, when you call it as a method on `Test.Base64Encode()`, `this` will refer to `Test` and `btoa` grumps about that.

> What's the correct way to fix this particular error?

You will need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) it to the expected context:

```
Base64Encode = window.btoa
  ? window.btoa.bind(window)
  : CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.bind()`:

```
var Test = {
    Base64Encode: function() {
      if (window.btoa)
        return window.btoa.bind(window);

      return CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify;
    }()
};
```

You got the error because you invoked the function via that object property reference. When you do that, the value of `this` is set to a reference to the object involved. The `btoa()` function doesn't like that (for who knows what reason), but `.bind()` creates a wrapper function for you that ensures the proper `this`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as that btoa function is a member function of Window class. And so it has to be called with this set to `window`.

In order it to work in your setup you should call it this way:

```
Test.Base64Encode.call(window,"Please work.");
```

Comment: It's unnecessary to write this out everytime you call it, especially if the fallback is in use it's even completely unnecessary. Binding it during assignment is a better choice.

Comment: That's true. But I would start from rethinking of original design, something is conceptually wrong there if such problem arises.